# I can't find creating custom starter app in the cli

Tags: flutter

When I use the cli to create a flutter app, a template app is created by google.

My question is, is there a way to create a custom template app instead of the default counter app by google, when I use the "flutter create my_app"?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

Create a simple, templated Flutter app, using the command

```
 flutter create my_app
```

this argument commands are helpful to customize your starter app

```
--org
```

The organization responsible for your new Flutter project, in reverse domain name
notation. This string is used in Java package names and as prefix in the iOS bundle
identifier.
(defaults to "com.example")

```
--description
```

The description to use for your new Flutter project. This string ends up in the
pubspec.yaml file.
(defaults to "A new Flutter project.")

```
-i, --ios-language
```

you can set ios language from `objc, swift`

```
 -a, --android-language
```

you can set ios language from `java, kotlin`

```
--platforms
```

The platforms supported by this project. This argument only works when the --template is
set to app or plugin. Platform folders (e.g. android/) will be generated in the target
project. When adding platforms to a plugin project, the pubspec.yaml will be updated with
the requested platform. Adding desktop platforms requires the corresponding desktop
config setting to be enabled.
[ios (default), android (default), windows (default), linux (default), macos (default),
web (default)]

`-t, --template=<type>`
Specify the type of project to create.

*[app]*                (default) Generate a Flutter application.
*[module]*             Generate a project to add a Flutter module to an existing Android or iOS application.
*[package]*            Generate a shareable Flutter project containing modular Dart code.
*[plugin]*             Generate a shareable Flutter project containing an API in Dart code with a
platform-specific implementation for Android, for iOS code, or for both.

```
 -s, --sample=<id>
```

Specifies the Flutter code sample to use as the main.dart for an application. Implies
--template=app. The value should be the sample ID of the desired sample from the API
documentation website (http://docs.flutter.dev). An example can be found at
https://master-api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SingleChildScrollView-class.html

```
--list-samples=<path>
```

Specifies a JSON output file for a listing of Flutter code samples that can be created
with --sample.

Run `"flutter help"` to see global options.

Comment: thank you for your help.. maybe i didn't make myself clear, but i asked about creating a template in flutter instead of the default counter app by google...
thanks again...